# Deleting links from d3 node-graph shuffles labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i want to delete links from my d3.js node-graph. More precisely i find all links with the same source as a given id and delete the matching entries in my `graph.links`. This seems to work, but it kind of shuffles all my link-labels in terms, that the labels are at another link then before.

I prepared a JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/FFoDWindow/0nf1hod8/

and this is my `deleteLinks`-function.

```
deleteLinks = function(parentNodeId){

        var linksToChildren = link.filter(function(d){
            return d.source.id ==parentNodeId;
        });

        var correspondingLinkPath = linkPath.filter(function(d){
            return d.source.id ==parentNodeId;
        });

        linksToChildren._groups[0].forEach(function(link){
            var data = d3.select(link).data()[0];
            var indexOfLink = graph.links.indexOf(data);
            graph.links.splice(indexOfLink, 1);
        });
        update();
    }
```

Do you need more Information? Thank's for your help, FFoDWindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are reassigning the data, it is good to use a key function for the new data to match the existing elements which already have datum. Since you are deleting one element, the default index order assignment will not work.

D3 documentation: [Joining Data](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_data)

I added the following key function of linkPaths:

```
 linkPath = linkPathGroup
                .selectAll(".linkPath")
                .data(graph.links, function(d) {
         return d ? d.linkLabel : this.id;
        });
```

And the following for linkLabels:

```
    linkLabel = linkLabelGroup
        .selectAll(".linkLabel")
        .data(graph.links,
function(d) {
 return d ? 'T' + d.linkLabel : this.id;
});
```

Here is the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0ndogj6n/6/)

Comment: Hey @Marcelo , sorry for my late response, but your updated fiddle doesn't work. The labels are still shuffeled...